# How I can set search params when using @reach/router

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

How I can set search params when using @reach/router? I just used props.history.push but props.history still undefined. Here is my code when page state chage

```
const handleChangePage = page => {
    setPage(page)
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.pathname)
    props.history.push({
       pathname: props.location.pathname,
       search: query.toString(),
    })
    //???  I want to set page for url similar to /product?page=3&limit=4
}
```

Comment: `navigate('/product?page=3&limit=4')` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react router you must use `navigate` to change routes and not `history`

Also you would use `props.location.search` to get `query params`

```
const handleChangePage = page => {
    setPage(page)
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.pathname)
    const path = `${props.location.pathname}?${query.toString()}
    navigate(path);
}
```